# Mathematics of SVM Polynomial Kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

I am confused due to weak mathematical background:

Class 1 : $$x_1=(1,2),y=[+1] , x_2=(3,4),y=[+1]$$

Class 2 : $$x_3=(2,3),y=[-1] , x_4=(1,5),y=[-1]$$

I want to solve this mathematically with Polynomial kernel of d=2.

Any help with real numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the polynomial kernel of d=2 is essentially (from the book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning)
[image]

A solution is:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=2(x_1-2)^2-(x_2-3)^2-0.5=2x_1^2-8x_1-x_2^2+6x_2-1.5$$
To verify it:
$$f(1,2)=2-1-0.5=0.5>0$$
$$f(3,4)=2-1-0.5=0.5>0$$
$$f(2,3)=0-0-0.5=-0.5<0$$
$$f(1,2)=2-4-0.5=-2.5<0$$